# Go no install location for directory outside GOPATH error when run "go get"

Tags: go, gopath

Simple Go project, with a external dependence:

```
import (  
        "fmt"  
        "html"  
        "log"  
        "net/http"  
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"  
)
```

My path working fine for other tasks like run, build, etc.:
`GOPATH="/home/racar/go"`

But when I try to get a external package with "go get" command, I got this error:

> "go install: no install location for directory... outside GOPATH"

Edit:
I have set my PATH in ~/.bashrc: `export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: What is the path to your project?

Comment: Is your project within your `GOPATH`?

Comment: Thanks. Edit the question with my path definition. In my project I can run other go commands so GOPATH seems ok.

Comment: Could you review your workspace and directory layout with these references https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH and https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH?

Comment: Thanks @jeevatkm, second link pointed me the right direction. I set the GOBIN path and `go get` worked, `export GOBIN=$HOME/work/bin`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According with this link: [github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH](http://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH)

Is needed to set GOBIN path in bash file: `export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: This really helped me after struggling with this error for two days. Thank you.

Comment: Even though the link no longer mentions `GOBIN`, I did have to set this environment variable, and doing so fixed the "no install location error". This was on Go 1.13.3.